# Multiple URL aliases on the same node/product

Tags: commerce, path-aliases, 10

Create an alias for a node/product.

/admin/config/search/path/add

Create another alias pointing to the same node; /node/123 for example.

The first alias created is now 301'd to the last one defined.

How do we work around this?  The use case is a product catalogue where the same product can be reached from different taxonomy terms. The URL is needed to maintain the breadcrumb trail.

Is it possible to achieve the approach with the current version of Drupal (10.2.3)?

Comment: Very opinionated response: HTTP is stateless; a resource is supposed to be the same resource regardless of how you got to it, the breadcrumb shouldn't change depending on the referring URL

Comment: This is primarily for eCommerce sites - where a single product can appear in multiple categories (mugs / gifts / under-20) - a constant canonical URL is set on the ultimate product page - but the current viewing context can be different.  Shopify adopts this approach.

Comment: I think you can disable the behaviour globally, by changing `redirect.settings.auto_redirect` to false, but usually you'd want that functionality on for a public-facing site

Answer (score 0):

I ended up abandoning the idea of having multiple URL's for the same Product Node.  Instead - I construct a URL parameter value on the parent taxonomy page (using views and URL rewriting) - such that when the user clicks onto the PDP - they have a context from which we can then derive the breadcrumb.